Menus in Google and Bing Search Results
When you search for "scss" on Google and Bing, the results include a submenu with several links to their pages.


Which SEO markup does Google and Bing use for these menus?
I'd like this to happen for a site I'm working on - specifically, having my 5-item menu embedded in the search result, but I don't see anything on the Sass web page that looks like the source of this. Is there anything I can do, or is it witchcraft?
I've tried adding a sitemap.xml and "application/ld+json" with the WebPage schema.

These are known as "sitelinks". Please see the question marked as a duplicate and the other related questions available under our Search function here.

@dan Thanks for the answer. That's very helpful. Even ChatGPT didn't know they were "sitelinks".
